# How do use xsl to select one entry in a table and entries above and below it?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an xml feed for displaying a football league table.  I would like to be able to filter the table to only display one particular team and a variable number of entries above and below it.

For example, out of a league of 24 teams I would like to display team A and the 3 higher positioned teams and 3 lower positioned teams, I am currently using xsl to format the data, however I cant figure out how to do this.  Would it even be with xsl?

Comment: Yes, XSLT would be good for this. Can you post some sample XML and a sample output? Including whatever XSLT you already have wouldn't hurt either. Also, is XSLT 2.0 an option?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have managed to select your "particular team", you can use the following-sibling and preceding-sibling axes to select your nearby items, using position() to limit the number of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a simplified example**:

Let's have this XML document (every element represents a "team") and the document represents all 10 teams, already sorted by points:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**If the team we are interested in is represented by `<num>05</num>` then this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vgivenTeam"
    select="/*/*[. = 5]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=

  "$vgivenTeam
 | $vgivenTeam/preceding-sibling::*[not(position() > 3)]
 | $vgivenTeam/following-sibling::*[not(position() > 3)]
 "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the above XML document, produces the wanted result** -- the three teams preceding the given one, the given team and the three teams following the given one:

```
<num>02</num>
<num>03</num>
<num>04</num>
<num>05</num>
<num>06</num>
<num>07</num>
<num>08</num>
```